# wifi does not work in ubuntu 13.10 and broadcom bcm4313 hardware

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, broadcom

I have already tried opensource as well as proprietary drivers but nothing seems to work. I'm stuck on this from 3 days, nothing seems to work.

First I installed the proprietary drivers with

```
apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This did not work, so I purged it and went for the default brcmsmac driver.

```
modprobe -rv wl
modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

Even this did not work. so installed b43 driver

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

I read the wireless wiki and all related questions on this but none of them seems to work for me.Please help..

Comment: Please edit your question to include: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e brcm -e wl and also: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this. Install the patch from here..

http://www.mindwerks.net/2013/10/wireless-bcm4312-with-the-3-10-and-3-11-kernels/